# Can't paste value of re.findall in cell using openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm unable to print the result of re.findall in an Excel cell, which is the result of another re.findall which is captured from a text file with multi-line data.

Below is the section of code from the entire code where I am facing a problem.

---

```
import openpyxl,os,re       # -- Import

pyro_asr920_dir = '{}\\'.format(os.getcwd())        # -- MARK DIRECTORIES

input_asr920_robot_pid_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Data_Workbook.xlsm', keep_vba = True)     # -- OPEN EXCEL
input_asr920_robot_pid_tpd_sheet = input_asr920_robot_pid_wb['Topology-Ports_Details']

wduplinka = open(os.path.join(pyro_asr920_dir, 'DELSNACAG01C7606-logs.txt'),'r')       # -- OPEN MULTILINE TEXT FILE
uplinkacontent = wduplinka.read()

PreBBa = re.findall( r'{}[\s\S]*?!\ni'.format('interface TenGigabitEthernet4/2'), uplinkacontent)       # -- GET REQUIRED SUBSTRING WITH MATCH CRITERIA IN BETWEEN

print(PreBBa)
output01 = '''
['interface TenGigabitEthernet4/2\n isis metric 10 level-2\n!\ni']'''

for line in PreBBa:     # - 01 > I CAN PRINT THIS ON EXCEL CELL
    input_asr920_robot_pid_tpd_sheet['H27'] = line[:-1]
    print(line[:-1])
    print('-----------')
output02 = '''
interface TenGigabitEthernet4/2
 isis metric 10 level-2
!'''
# ----------------------------------------------------------------- UNABLE TO GET VALUES IN CELL

for line in PreBBa:     # - 02 > I CAN'T PRINT THIS ON EXCEL CELL {THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK}
    if 'ospf' in line:
        theOSPF = re.findall(r'{}[\s\S]*?{}'.format(' ip ospf','\n c'), line)
        input_asr920_robot_pid_tpd_sheet['C47'] = 'Yes'
    else:
        input_asr920_robot_pid_tpd_sheet['C47'] = 'No'          # UNABLE TO GETRESULT IN EXCEL
        output03 = '''No'''
# -----------------------------------------------------------------
    metric = re.findall(r'{}[\s\S]*?{}'.format('metric ',' '), str(line))
    metric = re.findall(r'\d+',str(metric))
    input_asr920_robot_pid_tpd_sheet['C46'].value = metric[0]   # UNABLE TO GETRESULT IN EXCEL

    print(metric)
    output04 = '''10'''
# -----------------------------------------------------------------

input_asr920_robot_pid_wb.save('Data_Workbook.xlsm')

wduplinka.close()
input_asr920_robot_pid_wb.close()
print('TEST COMPLETED')
```

---

Some content of Text file is as below:

---

```
DELSNACAG01C7606#sh running-config 
Load for five secs: 18%/1%; one minute: 26%; five minutes: 26%
Time source is NTP, 13:43:23.718 IST Fri Aug 16 2019

Building configuration...

Current configuration : 228452 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 21:15:56 IST Thu Aug 15 2019
! NVRAM config last updated at 06:42:52 IST Sat Aug 10 2019 by cor382499
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet4/2
 isis metric 10 level-2
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet4/3
!
end
```

Comment: Do you get an error message of some kind (if yes, please edit and include this in your post), or simply no detectable outcome from the code you have highlighted?

Comment: {output01 / output02} are successfully printed in cell, but unable to get result of {output03 / output04}

Comment: So, no error message, just no 'Yes' or 'No' value showing in cell C47?

Comment: Yes, there is error message 'ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))' for output04 with 'metric' but there is no error for 'metric[0]' even cell in sheet are blank

Comment: {output01 / output02}  and {output03 / output04} .. are Just for reference that what output i wants to past in sheet cell

Comment: Can you please show the content of `PreBBa` -- or at least enough of it so we can make an assessment on whether your regex results will actually contain anything or not.

Comment: that's what the problem is, I can see results in CMD but C47 & C46 cell are blank in sheet.

Comment: Can you please edit your original post, and paste this section of the text file into it and apply appropriate formatting so we can see linebreaks. Many thanks!

Comment: Added the file content.. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, using the data you provided, I have run a close match to your code on my machine and I get the expected results: I get 'No' in cell C47 and I get 10 in cell C46. Do you have a debug environment set up? Are you able to put a breakpoint on those lines to absolutely confirm you know what values _should_ be written to the cells? Aside from that, the only other questions I can think of are what version of python and openpyxl are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 3.7.4 & openpyxl 2.6.2, that's really confusing why dont I get those results in C47 and C46.. the Code is clear, I have tried in several combinations then finally posted in stackoverflow.

Comment: There was no issue in Code but in .xlsm file which i have sorted 2days back but forgot to post, Thanks MurrayW for all of your inputs.